# Why does my function for customizing boxplot not work?

Tags: customization, boxplot, axis-labels

I'm trying to customize a boxplot for publishing by increasing the font size of the x labels.
I'm following instructions given here: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html

I tried to predefine parameters using this function:

```
par(font.xlab=2)
```

or

```
par(font.lab=2)
```

but neither worked.

I then tried to write them directly into a high level plotting function

```
boxplotDL<-boxplot(dlswlbri~kateg, data=data, col='lightgray', medcol='transparent', whisklty = 1, boxlwd=2, whisklwd=2, staplelwd=2, font.lab=2,outline=FALSE)
```

All other customizing commands worked (col, medcol,whisklty, etc.) except for font.lab.

What am i missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried playing around with these sizes?

```
par(cex.axis=2)
par(cex.lab=2)
```

Comment: Thanks Haithan, I tried hem and par(cex.axis=2) works for the label fon size, which solves my problem. Just wondering why par(cex.lab=2) doesn't work, cause i would think that's the one referring to the label and the other one referring to the axis. Anyway, thanks, this worked!